# VS 2017 Database Project “unresolved reference to object” Error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-data-tools

Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools for Visual Studio 2017 (SSDT) Version 15.7.4

I have a Data Warehouse that I now want to manage with a SSDT SQL Server Database (SSDb) project(s).  The DW has separate Extract/Cleanse/Transform/DataWarehouse databases.  I have a number of SP's and UDF in the master db.  The SP's are marked as system procedures via sp_MS_marksystemobject.  These generic SP's and UDF's may be used in all the DW databases.

I've created a SSDb project for each database, added a reference to master (both with and without the Suppress errors checkbox ticked, and imported my database objects with all options (objects) ticked.  I've also selected Tools --> Options --> SQL Server Tools --> Online Editing --> Resolve references to system views and master database objects.  I've rebooted and restared SSDT.

I'm getting these errors:

```
------ Build started: Project: MyDWName, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\SQL\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Roslyn\csc.exe /noconfig /nowarn:1701,1702,2008 /nostdlib+ /errorreport:prompt /warn:4 /define:DEBUG;TRACE /errorendlocation /preferreduilang:en-US /highentropyva+ /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\mscorlib.dll" /debug+ /debug:full /optimize- /out:obj\Debug\MyDWName.dll /ruleset:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\SQL\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\\Rule Sets\MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset" /subsystemversion:6.00 /target:library /warnaserror- /utf8output "C:\Users\FUBAR\AppData\Local\Temp\.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.SqlClrAttributes.cs"
        Loading project references...
        Loading project files...
        Building the project model and resolving object interdependencies...
        Validating the project model...
Y:\SSIS\MySSDTSolution\MyDWName\Security\SAS_SQL_Admin.sql(1,1): Error:  SQL71501: User: [SAS_SQL_Admin] has an unresolved reference to Login [SAS_SQL_Admin].
Y:\SSIS\MySSDTSolution\MyDWName\Security\DOMAIN_user.sql(1,13): Error:  SQL70527: 'DOMAIN\user' is not a valid name because it contains characters that are not valid.
Y:\SSIS\MySSDTSolution\MyDWName\Security\DOMAIN_anotheruser.sql(2,27): Warning:  SQL71502: User: [DOMAIN\anotheruser] has an unresolved reference to Schema [DOMAIN\anotheruser].
Y:\SSIS\MySSDTSolution\MyDWName\dbo\Stored Procedures\uspDeleteTempTables.sql(10,67): Warning:  SQL71502: Procedure: [dbo].[uspDeleteTempTables] has an unresolved reference to object [sys].[sysprocesses].[spid].
Y:\SSIS\MySSDTSolution\MyDWName\dbo\Stored Procedures\uspDeleteTempTables.sql(10,26): Warning:  SQL71502: Procedure: [dbo].[uspDeleteTempTables] has an unresolved reference to object [sys].[sysprocesses].[nt_username].
Y:\SSIS\MySSDTSolution\MyDWName\dbo\Stored Procedures\uspDeleteTempTables.sql(10,44): Warning:  SQL71502: Procedure: [dbo].[uspDeleteTempTables] has an unresolved reference to object [sys].[sysprocesses].
Done building project "MyDWName.sqlproj" -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded or up-to-date, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

For the SQL71502 Procedure warning, if I change sys.sysprocesses to master.sys.sysprocesses, the warning goes away.  But I have a reference to master, shouldn't that work???

For the SQL71501 error, I don't see any invalid characters in the username.  If I paste the exact code into SSMS, there are no errors.  Other users have the same DOMAIN\username syntax w/o error.

For the SQL70527 error, it is a user with default schema of dbo, and Owned Schema and Membership of db_owner.  The imported text was:

```
CREATE USER [SAS_SQL_Admin];
```

However, scripting this user in SSMS:

```
CREATE USER [SAS_SQL_Admin] WITHOUT LOGIN WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo];
```

Pasting this text into SSDT, the error went away.  Three hours of Googling down, one problem solved.  Is this a bug in SSDT?  Shouldn't it import the same definition that SSMS generates?

In another SSDb project, I'm getting these errors:

```
------ Build started: Project: MyDb (Databases\MyDb), Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\SQL\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Roslyn\csc.exe /noconfig /nowarn:1701,1702,2008 /nostdlib+ /errorreport:prompt /warn:4 /define:DEBUG;TRACE /errorendlocation /preferreduilang:en-US /highentropyva+ /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\mscorlib.dll" /debug+ /debug:full /optimize- /out:obj\Debug\RLDX_Extract.dll /ruleset:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\SQL\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\\Rule Sets\MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset" /subsystemversion:6.00 /target:library /warnaserror- /utf8output "C:\Users\FUBAR\AppData\Local\Temp\.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1.SqlClrAttributes.cs"
        Loading project references...
        Loading project files...
        Building the project model and resolving object interdependencies...
        Validating the project model...
Y:\SSIS\MySSDTSolution\MyDWName\MyDb\meta\Views\vwJob_Status_Comma.sql(9,8): Error:  SQL71501: View: [meta].[vwJob_Status_Comma] contains an unresolved reference to an object. Either the object does not exist or the reference is ambiguous because it could refer to any of the following objects: [master].[dbo].[fn_MoH_RightJustify] or [meta].[Job_Status].[master]::[dbo].[fn_MoH_RightJustify].
Y:\SSIS\MySSDTSolution2\MyDWName2\RLDX_Extract\meta\Views\vwJob_Status_Comma.sql(13,8): Error:  SQL71501: View: [meta].[vwJob_Status_Comma] contains an unresolved reference to an object. Either the object does not exist or the reference is ambiguous because it could refer to any of the following objects: [master].[dbo].[fn_MoH_RightJustify] or [meta].[Job_Status].[master]::[dbo].[fn_MoH_RightJustify].
...
Y:\SSIS\MySSDTSolution\MyDWName\MyDb\Security\NSWDOH_anotheruser.sql(2,27): Warning:  SQL71502: User: [NSWDOH\anotheruser] has an unresolved reference to Schema [NSWDOH\anotheruser].
Done building project "RLDX_MyDb.sqlproj" -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded or up-to-date, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Here is the definition of the view:

```
CREATE VIEW [meta].[vwJob_Status_Comma] AS
SELECT Job_ID
    ,Job_Level
    ,Job_Name
    ,Job_RunDate
    ,Job_StartTime
    ,Job_EndTime
    ,master.dbo.fn_MoH_RightJustify(FORMAT(Job_ElapsedSeconds,'N0'),18,DEFAULT) AS Job_ElapsedSeconds
    ,Job_ElapsedTime
    ,DataExtract_StartTime
    ,DataExtract_EndTime
    ,master.dbo.fn_MoH_RightJustify(FORMAT(RowCountSource,'N0'),15,DEFAULT) AS RowCountSource
    ,master.dbo.fn_MoH_RightJustify(FORMAT(RowCountInserted,'N0'),15,DEFAULT) AS RowCountInserted
    ,master.dbo.fn_MoH_RightJustify(FORMAT(RowCountChanged,'N0'),15,DEFAULT) AS RowCountChanged
    ,master.dbo.fn_MoH_RightJustify(FORMAT(RowCountNoChange,'N0'),15,DEFAULT) AS RowCountNoChange
    ,master.dbo.fn_MoH_RightJustify(FORMAT(RowCountDeleted,'N0'),15,DEFAULT) AS RowCountDeleted
    ,master.dbo.fn_MoH_RightJustify(FORMAT(RowCountTarget,'N0'),15,DEFAULT) AS RowCountTarget
    ,Job_Step
    ,Job_Status
    ,SubmittedBy
FROM meta.Job_Status
```

Questions:

1) Any idea why a valid user object in SSMS would generate this error in SSDT:

> 'DOMAIN\user' is not a valid name because it contains characters that are not valid.

2) I would like to manage user objects in the SSDT project.  I prefer the visibility of the objects in the project.  Is this a bad idea/not best practice?

3) This error message is completely throwing me:

> [master].[dbo].[fn_MoH_RightJustify] or [meta].[Job_Status].[master]::[dbo].[fn_MoH_RightJustify].

What is [meta].[Job_Status].[master]**::**[dbo].[fn_MoH_RightJustify]???  There is no [master] column in the Job_Status table.

4) Are all schema definitions imported by SSDT?  Do I need to manually create (some of) them?

5) The DW databases have a lot of synonyms.  Does SSDT handle synonyms properly?

Thanks...

**Edit:**
The reason the SP's are in master is I need them to execute within the context of the current database connection.  I tried a separate Tools database but couldn't get that to work.  See http://sqlserverplanet.com/dba/making-a-procedure-available-in-all-databases.

Since the SP's are there, I put the UDF's there as well to be consistent.

I use synonyms instead of three level names, i.e. dbo.fn_MoH_CleanString instead of master.dbo.fn_MoH_CleanString.

And I think I'm starting to "see" the problem.  When I added a reference to master, SSDT used a **static** copy of master based on the version of SQL Server I've configured.  If I view the .sqlproj file in an editor, I see:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <ArtifactReference Include="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\SQL\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\Extensions\SqlServer\130\SqlSchemas\master.dacpac">
    <HintPath>$(DacPacRootPath)\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\Extensions\SqlServer\130\SqlSchemas\master.dacpac</HintPath>
    <SuppressMissingDependenciesErrors>True</SuppressMissingDependenciesErrors>
    <DatabaseVariableLiteralValue>master</DatabaseVariableLiteralValue>
  </ArtifactReference>
</ItemGroup>
```

I thought the reference to master resulted in dynamic, run-time checking of master.

I can't create a dacpac of master from SSMS - a shortcoming of SSMS - but can from SSDT.  However, I got this error:

```
/****** Operation Steps ******/
Step 'Extracting schema from database'. Progress: Pending
Step 'Resolving references in schema model'. Progress: Pending
Step 'Validating schema model'. Progress: Pending
Step 'Extracting schema'. Progress: Pending
Step 'Extracting schema'. Progress: Running
Step 'Extracting schema from database'. Progress: Running
Step 'Extracting schema from database'. Progress: Completed
Step 'Resolving references in schema model'. Progress: Running
Step 'Resolving references in schema model'. Progress: Completed
Step 'Validating schema model'. Progress: Running
Step 'Validating schema model'. Progress: Failed
Step 'Extracting schema'. Progress: Failed

/****** Logged Messages ******/
Extracting schema (Start)
Gathering error messages
Gathering cryptographic providers
Gathering credentials
Gathering logins
Gathering server roles
Gathering server role memberships
Gathering linked servers
Gathering linked server logins
Gathering routes
Gathering ddl triggers
Gathering encrypted and clr ddl triggers
Gathering event notifications
Gathering server audits
Gathering server audit specifications
Gathering event notifications
Gathering database options
Gathering users
Gathering roles
Gathering application roles
Gathering role memberships
Gathering filegroups
Gathering files
Gathering full-text catalogs
Gathering assemblies
Gathering certificates
Gathering asymmetric keys
Gathering symmetric keys
Gathering encrypted symmetric keys
Gathering database encryption keys
Gathering schemas
Gathering XML schema collections
Gathering user-defined data types
Gathering user-defined types
Gathering table types
Gathering unique keys for table types
Gathering primary keys for table types
Gathering check constraints for table types
Gathering default constraints for table types
Gathering partition functions
Gathering partition schemes
Gathering functions
Gathering encrypted functions
Gathering aggregates
Gathering procedures
Gathering procedures
Gathering encrypted procedures
Gathering encrypted procedures
Gathering encrypted procedures
Gathering tables
Gathering tables
Gathering primary keys
Gathering unique constraints
Gathering foreign keys
Gathering default constraints
Gathering check constraints
Gathering views
Gathering encrypted views
Gathering indexes
Gathering statistics
Gathering full-text index stoplists
Gathering search property lists
Gathering search properties
Gathering full-text indexes
Gathering column store indexes
Gathering spatial indexes
Gathering XML indexes
Gathering Selective XML indexes
Gathering encrypted triggers
Gathering triggers
Gathering encrypted and clr ddl triggers
Gathering ddl triggers
Gathering synonyms
Gathering defaults
Gathering data constraint uddt bindings
Gathering rules
Gathering data constraint uddt bindings
Gathering message types
Gathering queues
Gathering contracts
Gathering services
Gathering routes
Gathering event notifications
Gathering remote service bindings
Gathering broker priorities
Gathering database audit specifications
Gathering signatures
Gathering signatures
Gathering data compression options
Gathering sequence types
Gathering extended properties
Gathering extended properties
Gathering extended properties
Gathering extended properties
Error validating element [dbo].[ssisprojects]: View: [dbo].[ssisprojects] has an unresolved reference to object [SSISDB].[catalog].[packages].
Error validating element [dbo].[ssisprojects]: View: [dbo].[ssisprojects] has an unresolved reference to object [SSISDB].[catalog].[projects].
Error validating element [dbo].[ssisprojects]: View: [dbo].[ssisprojects] contains an unresolved reference to an object. Either the object does not exist or the reference is ambiguous because it could refer to any of the following objects: [SSISDB].[catalog].[packages].[p], [SSISDB].[catalog].[packages].[project_id] or [SSISDB].[catalog].[projects].[p].
Error validating element [dbo].[ssisprojects]: View: [dbo].[ssisprojects] contains an unresolved reference to an object. Either the object does not exist or the reference is ambiguous because it could refer to any of the following objects: [SSISDB].[catalog].[packages].[j], [SSISDB].[catalog].[projects].[j] or [SSISDB].[catalog].[projects].[project_id].
Error validating element [dbo].[ssisprojects]: View: [dbo].[ssisprojects] has an unresolved reference to object [SSISDB].[catalog].[folders].
Error validating element [dbo].[ssisprojects]: View: [dbo].[ssisprojects] contains an unresolved reference to an object. Either the object does not exist or the reference is ambiguous because it could refer to any of the following objects: [SSISDB].[catalog].[folders].[j], [SSISDB].[catalog].[packages].[j], [SSISDB].[catalog].[projects].[folder_id] or [SSISDB].[catalog].[projects].[j].
Error validating element [dbo].[ssisprojects]: View: [dbo].[ssisprojects] contains an unresolved reference to an object. Either the object does not exist or the reference is ambiguous because it could refer to any of the following objects: [SSISDB].[catalog].[folders].[f], [SSISDB].[catalog].[folders].[folder_id], [SSISDB].[catalog].[packages].[f] or [SSISDB].[catalog].[projects].[f].
Error validating element [dbo].[ssisprojects]: View: [dbo].[ssisprojects] contains an unresolved reference to an object. Either the object does not exist or the reference is ambiguous because it could refer to any of the following objects: [SSISDB].[catalog].[folders].[f], [SSISDB].[catalog].[folders].[name], [SSISDB].[catalog].[packages].[f] or [SSISDB].[catalog].[projects].[f].
Error validating element [dbo].[ssisprojects]: View: [dbo].[ssisprojects] contains an unresolved reference to an object. Either the object does not exist or the reference is ambiguous because it could refer to any of the following objects: [SSISDB].[catalog].[folders].[j], [SSISDB].[catalog].[packages].[j], [SSISDB].[catalog].[projects].[j] or [SSISDB].[catalog].[projects].[name].
Error validating element [dbo].[ssisprojects]: View: [dbo].[ssisprojects] contains an unresolved reference to an object. Either the object does not exist or the reference is ambiguous because it could refer to any of the following objects: [SSISDB].[catalog].[folders].[p], [SSISDB].[catalog].[packages].[name], [SSISDB].[catalog].[packages].[p] or [SSISDB].[catalog].[projects].[p].
Error validating element [dbo].[ssisprojects]: View: [dbo].[ssisprojects] contains an unresolved reference to an object. Either the object does not exist or the reference is ambiguous because it could refer to any of the following objects: [SSISDB].[catalog].[folders].[f], [SSISDB].[catalog].[folders].[name], [SSISDB].[catalog].[packages].[f] or [SSISDB].[catalog].[projects].[f].
Error validating element [dbo].[ssisprojects]: View: [dbo].[ssisprojects] contains an unresolved reference to an object. Either the object does not exist or the reference is ambiguous because it could refer to any of the following objects: [SSISDB].[catalog].[folders].[j], [SSISDB].[catalog].[packages].[j], [SSISDB].[catalog].[projects].[j] or [SSISDB].[catalog].[projects].[name].
Error validating element [dbo].[ssisprojects]: View: [dbo].[ssisprojects] contains an unresolved reference to an object. Either the object does not exist or the reference is ambiguous because it could refer to any of the following objects: [SSISDB].[catalog].[folders].[p], [SSISDB].[catalog].[packages].[name], [SSISDB].[catalog].[packages].[p] or [SSISDB].[catalog].[projects].[p].
Error validating element [dbo].[ssisprojects].[Folder]: Computed Column: [dbo].[ssisprojects].[Folder] contains an unresolved reference to an object. Either the object does not exist or the reference is ambiguous because it could refer to any of the following objects: [SSISDB].[catalog].[folders].[f], [SSISDB].[catalog].[folders].[name], [SSISDB].[catalog].[packages].[f] or [SSISDB].[catalog].[projects].[f].
Error validating element [dbo].[ssisprojects].[Project]: Computed Column: [dbo].[ssisprojects].[Project] contains an unresolved reference to an object. Either the object does not exist or the reference is ambiguous because it could refer to any of the following objects: [SSISDB].[catalog].[folders].[j], [SSISDB].[catalog].[packages].[j], [SSISDB].[catalog].[projects].[j] or [SSISDB].[catalog].[projects].[name].
Error validating element [dbo].[ssisprojects].[Package]: Computed Column: [dbo].[ssisprojects].[Package] contains an unresolved reference to an object. Either the object does not exist or the reference is ambiguous because it could refer to any of the following objects: [SSISDB].[catalog].[folders].[p], [SSISDB].[catalog].[packages].[name], [SSISDB].[catalog].[packages].[p] or [SSISDB].[catalog].[projects].[p].
Extracting schema (Failed)
```

Should I just turn off verify dacpac when I create it?